# Abstraction with respective to end user users perspective

Tags: oop, abstraction

its very simple and basic question.

I have a query regarding abstraction:

Abstraction is defined as Showing what is necessary from user's perspective! its filtering un-necessary info from users perspective.

its right.

example:

Implementation of Abstraction

To implement abstraction let's take an example of a car. We knows a car, Car is made of name of car, color of car, steering, gear, rear view mirror, brakes, silencer, exhaust system, diesel engine, car battery, car engine and other internal machine details etc.

Now lets think in terms of Car rider or a person who is riding a car. So to drive a car what a car rider should know from above category before he starts a car driving.

Necessary things means compulsory to know before starting a car

1. Name of Car
2. Color of Car
3. Steering
4. Rear View Mirror
5. Brakes
6. Gear

Unnecessary things means  not that compulsory to know for a Car rider

1. Internal Details of a Car
2. Car Engine
3. Diesel Engine
4. Exhaust System
5. Silencer

In Driver perspective. That is okay. Its classic implementation of the Abstraction.

Now, what if I am different user of the class, say Mechanic??? it will be very weird to define same class for me with different access modifiers.
Right?

Please let know.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to provide multiple simplified interfaces for a complex class or set of classes.

The standard way to do this is by implementing the facade design pattern. This will also encourage you to put each of the different aspects of the car into its own class and aggregate these classes only when the full functionality is required.